# efficient check for value change in array of floats in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

i want to optimize an OpenGL application, and one hotspot is
doing expensive handling ( uploading to graphics card ) of
relatively small arrays ( 8-64 values ) where sometimes the
values change but most of the times stay constant. So most
efficient solution would be to upload the array only when
it has changed.

Of course the simplest way would be setting flags whenever
the data is changed, but this would need many code
changes, and for a quick test i would like to know the
possible performance gains, before too much work has to
be done.

So i thought of a quick check ( like a murmur hash etc )
in memory if the data has changed from frame to frame and
decide uploding after this check. so the question is, how
could i eg. XOR an array of values like

float vptr[] = { box.x1,box.y1, box.x1,box.y2, box.x2,box.y2, box.x2,box.y1 };

together to detect reliably value changes?

Best & thanks,
Heiner

Comment: This is exactly why **encapsulation** matters: if the values had been stored in an object whose type provided an accessor for setting the value, adding a flag would require changes in only one place.

Comment: @PeteBecker True in general. At the same time, though, graphics code is usually performance-critical and thus often has to sacrifice niceness for speed. Could be the case here.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for answering *without reading*. the question is not about c++ or object oriented design. the question is valid in many other circumstances: how to hash quickly a handful of floats?

Comment: @Angew - there's no extra overhead for a proper accessor. The problem here is that graphics code is always written as if there were invisible overheads.

Comment: @wendy_44 - that's why I **didn't** answer.

Comment: `memcmp` may well be fastest on data that small.

Comment: its not two distinct arrays, rather the same array in different times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ming, thank you for the intrinsic speedup, i will have a look into this.

```
float vptr[] = { box.x1,box.y1, box.x1,box.y2, box.x2,box.y2, box.x2,box.y1 };
unsigned hashval h = 0;
for(int i=...)
{
   h ^= (unsigned&) vptr[i];
}
```

dead simple, worked for the really tiny arrays. compiler should be able to auto-vectorize, size of array is known. have to test for larger arrays.
origin: [Hash function for floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238122/hash-function-for-floats)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using intel, you could look into intel intrinsics.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide gives you an interactive reference where you can explore. There are a bunch of instructions for comparing multiple integers or doubles in one instruction, which is a nice speed-up.

Comment: ... if your compiler supports intel intrinsics, if it supports the family of intel intrinsics that you need and you always need to enable and include the right headers most of the time. Compilers usually put intrinsics on the same level as _builtin functions_ so you need a look the compiler's manual to deal with intrinsics.