# How to find how many times a number has been repeated in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

I am confused how to find out how many times a number has been repeated in a user input. I am able to input numbers and see which numbers are repeating but am unsure of how to print out each inputed number and how many times that number was used. This is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    double numArray[100];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    int count = 0;

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    printf("Enter any number of integers between 0 and 99 followed a non-numeric: \n");

    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
        if (scanf("%lf", &numArray[x]) != 1)
            break;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
    counter = counter - 1;

    for(x = 0; x < counter; x++){
        for(y = x + 1; y < counter; y++){
            if(numArray[x] == numArray[y]){
                printf("duplicate found: %lf\n", numArray[x]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This is a *classic* frequency problem. You have a range of numbers `0-99` (100 values), so simply declare an array with 100 values (all initialized `0`) e.g. `int freq[100] = {0};`. Then in your read loop, do `freq[numArray[x]]++;`. When you are done, you now have `freq` whose elements contain the number of times each value was entered. (note: this applies to *integer* values -- the number of possible `long double` values between `0-100` is huge)

Comment: If you do need to accept and count the frequency of *floating-point* numbers, then you will be best served by creating a *hash table* and counting, for example, the collisions for each value as a representation of your number of repeats. There are a host of subtle issues you will need to address regarding floating-point comparisons and you may not be able to cover all floating point levels of precision between any two values given the limitations of the **IEEE-754 Floating Point Format**. See [**Hash function for floats**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238122/hash-function-for-floats)

Comment: Look for how counting sort is implemented. You can make use of the data structure used there ( without the sorting ) for your frequency counting.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing for my initial comment, whenever you want to capture the frequency of values within a range, you generally want to declare an array and let each element of the array represent one value within the range. (this applies to integer input). For example, in your case, if you want to find the frequency of the integer values entered by a user in the range of `0-99`, you would declare an array with 100 elements (representing values `0-99`) and initialize all values to `0`.**[1]**

Then each time the user enters a valid value in the range, you increment that element. For example, if your user enters `58`, you would increment `array[58] =  array[58] + 1;` (or simply `array[58]++;`). The value of `array[58]` is now `1` indicating the user has entered `58` once. (if `58` was entered again, it would be `2`, and so on...)

This lends itself nicely for your input loop. You simply declare say `int x;` and in your `scanf` call, you fill `x`, validate it is within the range and then `array[x]++;` For example with your `numarray` declared as `int [100]`, you could do **[2]**:

```
#define NMAX 100  /* define constants, avoid 'magic' numbers in code */
...
for (;;) {  /* loop until non-numeric encountered */
    int x;
    if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)     /* check for non-numeric */
        break;
    if (x < 0 || x >= NMAX) {   /* validate value in range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: value outside of range -- "
                 "try again.\n");
        continue;      /* if out of range - get new number */
    }
    numarray[x]++;     /* increment frequency at element x */
}
```

Now in your case the `0-99` exactly matches the *zero-based array indexing* used in C, but you can index any range simply by adjusting the indexes. For example, if you were interested in a range of `50-150` you would simply adjust the indexes as required (e.g. `numarray[x-50]++;`)

However, in your code, it is quite unclear what your actual intent is. For instance you ask for values between `0-99`, but then declare `numarray` as a *floating-point* type. If your intent was to have the user enter whole number values, then your array type should be an *integer* type instead. That reduces to the classic frequency problem which you could handle simply in a manner similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NMAX 100  /* define constants, avoid 'magic' numbers in code */

int main (void){

    int i, numarray[NMAX] = {0};  /* C favors all lower-case over
                                   * camelCase variable names  */

    printf ("Enter any number of integers between 0 and 99 "
            "followed a non-numeric: \n");

    for (;;) {  /* loop until non-numeric encountered */
        int x;
        if (scanf("%d", &x) != 1)     /* check for non-numeric */
            break;
        if (x < 0 || x >= NMAX) {   /* validate value in range */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: value outside of range -- "
                    "try again.\n");
            continue;      /* if out of range - get new number */
        }
        numarray[x]++;     /* increment frequency at element x */
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NMAX; i++)   /* output frequency of values */
        printf (" %2d : %d times\n", i, numarray[i]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

For example, you can generate `500` values between `0-99` and output the frequency for each of the `500` numbers generated with something similar to the following:

```
$ ./bin/freqarray < <(for i in $(seq 1 500); do
printf " %d" $(($RANDOM %100)); done; echo "done")
Enter any number of integers between 0 and 99 followed a non-numeric:
  0 : 4 times
  1 : 7 times
  2 : 7 times
  3 : 4 times
  4 : 5 times
  5 : 11 times
  6 : 5 times
  7 : 5 times
  8 : 3 times
  9 : 8 times
 10 : 5 times
 ...
 90 : 8 times
 91 : 2 times
 92 : 5 times
 93 : 8 times
 94 : 4 times
 95 : 4 times
 96 : 8 times
 97 : 6 times
 98 : 4 times
 99 : 8 times
```

**Handling floating-point values**

Now if you truly wanted your user to enter *floating-point* values, e.g. `58.01831`, `58.01826538`, etc..., conceptually accounting for the frequency of each number isn't any difference, but the implementation is much more involved given the way *floating-point* numbers are stored in memory. See [**IEEE floating point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and the numerous post on this site. The problems related to floating point storage and exact comparison of random user input can become fairly involved -- quickly. Even for the range of `0-99` there are literally `4e+18`+ 64-bit values involved.

As noted in the second comment, one approach that can help is to *hash* the input values and store the *hashed* values in a *hash-table* to reduce the size of the array needed to track/store all values. You will have to balance precision you keep against storage size.

There is no way you could declare an array of `4e+18` elements. A *hash table* essentially provides a *storage and lookup* mechanism that can give you reasonable accuracy, and also provides a reasonable storage size. If the user enters 2-values that have the same *hash* a *collision* will be generated in your table, which you could use to indicate a duplicate entry. If that was your intent, then you will need to investigate the floating point hash functions available to meet your needs (which from your question, doesn't seem like what you intended, and it well beyond full-explanation here)

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. If your intent was different, then please edit the question and I'm happy to work with you further.

**footnote 1:** choose an array *type* capable of holding the maximum number of entries you expect, e.g. each `int` element  of the array can capture a maximum of `INT_MAX`, or `2147483647` repetitions (where an `int` is `32-bits`)

**footnote 2:** C generally favors variable names of all *lower-case*, and avoids the use of *camelCase* or *MixedCase* variable names; reserving all *upper-case* for constants and macros. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you.