# What are good hashing functions for hashing `n`-dimensional non-negative integer vectors whose sum less than or equal to order `m`?

Tags: data-structures, hash

What are good hashing functions for hashing `n`-dimensional non-negative integer vectors whose sum less than or equal to order `m`?

For example `m,n=2` will need to hash `(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2)`

What if `n>>m`?

I saw this answer [Hashing 2D, 3D and nD vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928725/hashing-2d-3d-and-nd-vectors) but not sure if this works well for integers instead of float.

Comment: Why would you think that it wouldn't work well with integers?

Comment: I think there may be better way to hash if we are only looking at a small subset of integers?

Comment: How small is the subset of integers? What are the ranges?

Comment: Does it need to be hashing? If you simply need a datastructure to store n-dimensional vectors, have a look at quadtrees, kd-trees, R-Trees, ...